# How to configure passwordEncoder in spring security config if i use Md5PasswordEncoder for password encryption?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

#### Encryption

```
Md5PasswordEncoder md5PasswordEncoder = new Md5PasswordEncoder();
md5PasswordEncoder.encodePassword(
    userRegistrationInfo.getPassword(), 
    AppConstants.MD5_PASSWORD_ENCODER_SALT);
```

#### Spring Security Configuration

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception { 
 
   auth
      .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
      .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}
    
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    PasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    return encoder;
}
```

I need to use `org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.Md5PasswordEncoder` for my password encryption. But I don't know how to configure `passwordEncoder()` in Spring security configuration.

Comment: md5 in 2017? Are you kidding?

Comment: can you suggest any secure encryption?

Comment: BCryptPasswordEncoder

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Security Config

---

```
                    @Autowired
                    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
                        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
                    }


            @Bean
                public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
                    PasswordEncoder encoder = new FlasherPasswordEncoder();
                    return encoder;
                }
```

PasswordEncoder MyOwn Implementation

---

```
        package com.flasher.config;

        import org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.Md5PasswordEncoder;
        import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

        public class FlasherPasswordEncoder implements PasswordEncoder {

            @Override
            public String encode(CharSequence rawPassword) {
                return new Md5PasswordEncoder().encodePassword(rawPassword.toString(), AppConstants.MD5_PASSWORD_ENCODER_SALT);

            }

            @Override
            public boolean matches(CharSequence rawPassword, String encodedPassword) {
                return new Md5PasswordEncoder().encodePassword(rawPassword.toString(), AppConstants.MD5_PASSWORD_ENCODER_SALT)
                        .equals(encodedPassword);
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 6):

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }
}



@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
    //implements PasswordEncoder and overide encode method with the MD5 protocol
    return new MD5PasswordEncoder();
}
```

Comment: This is supported until spring security 5 but with spring security 6.0, `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` is not available. Need to be replaced with `SecurityFilterChain`, also there are few changes to use userDetailsService and encoder.

Comment: @bh4r4th, a new answer for Spring 6 would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what your problem is. Md5PasswordEncoder has an emtpy constructor so you can simply

```
<bean id="passwordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.Md5PasswordEncoder ">
</bean>
```

And then pass it to your AuthenticationProvider (for example DaoAuthenticationProvider)

```
<bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="userDetailsService">
        <ref bean="yourUserDetailsService"/>
    </property>
    <property name="passwordEncoder">
        <ref bean="passwordEncoder"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

UPDATE: the op commented, that he is using a salt. 
That depends also on your authentication provider. If your are using the [DaoAuthenticationProvider](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/dao/DaoAuthenticationProvider.html) you can use the [setSaltSource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/dao/DaoAuthenticationProvider.html#setSaltSource-org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.SaltSource-) to set your salt source. Just add another property to the config refering to your salt-source-bean.

Comment: ah, now you edited your question... I leave this here anyway

Comment: but I'm using  a salt for encoding

Comment: Md5PasswordEncoder md5PasswordEncoder =new Md5PasswordEncoder();
        md5PasswordEncoder.encodePassword(userRegistrationInfo.getPassword(),AppConstants.MD5_PASSWORD_ENCODER_SALT);

Answer (score 1):

Spring Security 5 has been removed Md5PasswordEncoder.If you want to use MD5 encode you can customize :

```
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new PasswordEncoder() {
        @Override
        public String encode(CharSequence charSequence) {
            return getMd5(charSequence.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public boolean matches(CharSequence charSequence, String s) {
            return getMd5(charSequence.toString()).equals(s);
        }
    };
}

public static String getMd5(String input) {
    try {
        // Static getInstance method is called with hashing SHA
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");

        // digest() method called
        // to calculate message digest of an input
        // and return array of byte
        byte[] messageDigest = md.digest(input.getBytes());

        // Convert byte array into signum representation
        BigInteger no = new BigInteger(1, messageDigest);

        // Convert message digest into hex value
        String hashtext = no.toString(16);

        while (hashtext.length() < 32) {
            hashtext = "0" + hashtext;
        }

        return hashtext;
    }

    // For specifying wrong message digest algorithms
    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception thrown"
                + " for incorrect algorithm: " + e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not work for me. While debugging it enters to encode(CharSequence charSequence) method first and here charSequence is equal to userNotFoundPassword. After this matches() compares the md5 hash of 'userNotFoundPassword' and the received password hash and returns false of course

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        PasswordEncoder encoder = new Md5PasswordEncoder();
        return encoder;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
//MD5 encoder implementation
return new MD5PasswordEncoder();
}
```

Paste the above code below the following code under **SecurityConfig Class**:

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) 
throws Exception {
authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}
```